# VAR models: Effects of sparsity and magnitude disparities on VAR dynamics and possible solutions

Tags: count-data, vector-autoregression, sparse

In a VAR model involving two (or more) time series, if one series has sparse data with low counts, while the other series has lower sparsity and higher values, are there any statistical or technical reasons within the VAR modeling framework that might result in the larger series appearing to influence the behavior of the second series? Can we rely on such a model, or is it potentially biased due to the varying degrees of sparsity and value magnitudes between the series? If this model isn't trustworthy given the data characteristics, are there any methods to mitigate this bias and obtain a more accurate model in such a scenario?

Comment: What do you mean by *sparse data with low counts*? A series of nonnegative integers where many values are zeros?

Comment: By sparse data, I mean many zeros, and by low counts, I mean that the nonnegative integers are small (e.g., ranging from about 1 to 5), while the other series has higher values (e.g., ranging from 20 to 300). I can imagine that too many zeros can be a problem, as well as this disparity in the magnitude of values. Regarding the latter, maybe I could just standardize the values, but I am wondering if this would cause me to lose important information.